# How do I guarantee unique subscriptions in Orion Context Broker?

Tags: fiware-orion

In my setup I have one application that should subscribe to a specific kind of context change.
The application currently perform subscription at startup time. However if I restart the application, the subscription is duplicated. To overcome this issue I started to keep track of subscriptions in a database, so that I have an association between my application id and the latest subscription id.

Is there any way to achieve similar result in Orion (let's call it like "named subscriptions"), without using an external database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a planned subscription "browsing" operation in Orion development roadmap (see operation ID 45 in [this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4m624nmO3jRjNalGE11lFLQixnfCENMV6dc54wUCCg/edit#gid=0)) that could help in your case.

However, while this operation get implemented, one alternative to the one you mention (i.e. to keep subscription info in an external DB) would be to access to the Orion DB itself to get the subscription information. The datamodel (described [here](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#csubs_collection)) is pretty simple and getting the info is quite easy if you are familiar with MongoDB. Note that this solution  requires access to the Orion DB (i.e. it is feasible if you control your own instance of Orion).

**EDIT**: Given that different subscriptions may use the same reference, I'd recommend to use `_id` field to identify each subscription (`_id` field values are unique). NGSI doesn't include metadata in subscription, but you may associated subscription IDs with application using Orion itself, e.g. SubscriptionAssociation entities with two attributes, one for the application name and another for the subscription ID being associated

**EDIT:** since Orion 0.25.0, the `GET /v2/subscriptions` operation allows you to browse existing subscriptions.

Comment: Essentially you are suggesting to guess the application by the reference information, am I right?
Because in my case I do not have any reliable way to guess this association if I cannot attach some additional information to the subscription. Is there any field that can be used for this purpose (e.g., a metadata field)?

Comment: Given that different subscription may use the same reference, I'd recommend to use _id field to identify each subscription (_id field values are unique). NGSI doesn't include metadata in subscription, but you may associated subscription IDs with application using Orion itself, e.g. SubscriptionAssociation entities with two attributes, one for the application name and another for the subscription ID being associated.

Comment: I think this comment properly answer my question and cover my use case. I edited your answer.

Comment: I'm afraid that SOF reviewers have rejected you edit :( However, don't worry, the information is still there in the comments :) Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind providing another answer with the solution you proposed in the comment and the first line in this answer? I really think that one would be an acceptable answer, but not this one.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include that information.

Comment: Added information about subscription browsing operation in NGSIv2.