# How can i list my current subscription?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Earlier in the day, I have been trying to create a subscription for a specific entity to push the data to cosmos. the first try did not seem to work so I  create another which work.

However , I rebooted the Cygnus service and now the first subscription work.  So my data are pushed twice to Cosmos when they change. I want to unsubscribe to the first subscription but I didn't write down the subID.

Is there any way to list the current Subscription?  Or at least clear all of them to start from scratch and create only the needed subscription?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to reset my subscribtion by dropping the csubs collection on MongoDb . This collection list all the subscription, once you dropped it and create another good sub you're good to go! (Be sure you don't have important subscription , otherwise I don't not to delete safely without the SubID)

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.22 it is not yet possible to browse subscriptions.

However you can just store subscriptions in Orion itself, so that you can later use Orion to query for subscriptions. The topic has been discussed here: [How do I guarantee unique subscriptions in Orion Context Broker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782951/how-do-i-guarantee-unique-subscriptions-in-orion-context-broker)