# Stopping subscription without subscriptionId

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

**Is there a way to stop or change a subscription in case I lost the subscriptionId?** I tried creating a new subscription with the same type and id to get a new one but that didn't seem to work, any suggestion?

Comment: More than a question related to fiware-cygnus, this is related to fiware-orion. Please, try to change the tags (if such a thing is possible, I cannot do that).

Comment: The labels has been fixed

Answer (score 1):

Current Orion version (0.22.0) doesn't expose any operation to browse subscriptions, although it could be done from Orion DB if you have access to it. The topic has been discussed in [another Q&A post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782951/how-do-i-guarantee-unique-subscriptions-in-orion-context-broker), that you may find interesting.

Comment: So the short answer is NO? I cannot do that in this version, but you do plan on enabling this feature you call "browse subscriptions" in upcoming versions?